# How to use my registered providers with a dynamically created jersey resource class?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I just want to know how can we use our registered providers(MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter) with a dynamically created jersey resource class i.e. a jersey resource created programmatically via the programmatic jersey resource api such as

```
 Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
        resourceBuilder.path("helloworld/{name}");

        ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder = resourceBuilder.addMethod("POST");
        methodBuilder.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .handledBy(new MyInflector());
         Resource resource = resourceBuilder.build();
        registerResources(resource);
```

now how to use my registered MessageBodyReader and Writer in the MyInflector class which is as follows

```
public class MyInflector implements Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>{

    @Override
    public String apply(ContainerRequestContext arg0) {
        System.out.println("Processing request");
         MultivaluedMap<String, String> pParams =arg0.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
         InputStream stream=arg0.getEntityStream();
         if (stream != null) {
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();

                char[] buffer = new char[5120];
                try {
                    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
                    int n;
                    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return writer.toString();
            } else {
                return "";
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well you are making the resource method produce and consume both text/plain. So you need to make sure the reader and writer handle the same type. You also need to make sure the the `isReadable()` and `isWriteable()` is implemented correctly based on how you implement the inflector. Maybe you should read the chapter on [entity providers](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). It will go into more detail with what I'm talking about. Which readers and writers are chosen for the request should not change, whether you are using declared resources or programmatic.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha what i meant that just like we declare in regular jersey resource the post method 's parameter as the body of request how to do the same thing using this programmatic jersey resource api

Comment: Cast the `ContainerRequestContext` to `ContainerRequest`. Then use `containerRequest.readEntity(Pojo.class)`. If you had a reader to handle `Pojo.class`, then it would be used.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha sir you are a life saver pleae post this as an answer so i can accept it and don't forget to upvote the question if you didn't already do so;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is cast the `ContainerRequestContext` to `ContainerRequest` (which is a Jersey implementation of the `ContainerRequestContext` interface. With this class, you can call `containerRequest.readEntity(Pojo.class)`. This will cause the reader for the `Pojo.class` class to be called (assuming the content-type also matches with the media type the endpoint consumes).

```
@Override
public String apply(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    ContainerRequest containerRequest = (ContainerRequest)requestContext;
    Model model = containerRequest.readEntity(Model.class);
    ...
}
```